# How to display function value?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, function

I am using this function and declare display_error(),
but error display on my screen 
"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" 
help with us.

```
function display_error($nerrors = '')
        {
            if(isset($nerrors))
            {
            foreach($nerrors as $err)
            {
                echo $err->errors['existing_user_login'][0];

            }       

            }
        }
```

Comment: By your warning, it sound like $nerrors isnt an array. right before  if( isset( $nerrors ) ) add print_r($nerror) to check the content of the variable

Comment: What is `$nerrors = ''` for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your default parameter to the function is a string and not an array. Change that to an empty array:

```
function display_error($nerrors = array()) {
    foreach($nerrors as $err) {
        echo $err->errors['existing_user_login'][0];
    }
}
```

You can leave out the `if`, the loop won't run if the array is empty.